# Does It possible to use multiple common libraries in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have tried to build project in `gradle` with 3 modules, where: 
1) `module1` - common module with `expect` classes 
*empty build.gradle dependencies* 
2) `module2` - common module with `expect` classes and with dependency from module 1: 
build.gradle dependencies: `compile project(':module1')`  
2) `module3` - jvm platform module  
build.gradle dependencies: `expectedBy project(':module2')`

When I try to compile a project, it appears errors in compilation stage of `module3`, that classes from `module2` couldn't find classes from `module1`.

Kotlin 1.2.30 
Gradle 4.6 
Java 1.8_161

Does It possible to use multiple common modules together in one project? 
 And does it possible to have `expect` classes in each common module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, using common declarations from multiple common modules is not supported, but it is planned for future versions.

In particular, once the fix for [KT-22864](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/v2/issue/KT-22864) is released, it will allow you to add both `module1` and `module2` as `expectedBy` dependencies to `module3`. There's currently no public preview build with the fix, please stay tuned for 1.2.40 EAPs.

---

<sup>If you really want to try it early, you can use a dev build (e.g. `1.2.40-dev-754` from the `https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev` Maven repository).</sup>

<sup>You can also try a dev build of the IDE plugin (from [here](https://teamcity.jetbrains.com/viewLog.html?buildId=1344571&buildTypeId=Kotlin_dev_CompilerAllPlugins&tab=artifacts)) to make the IDE import and analyze multiple `expectedBy` dependencies properly (1.2.30 can only import one such dependency).</sup>

Comment: I have a similar problem, given `module1` that have classes that should be only used in tests, I add a dependency on them as `testCompile` in `module2`, and in `module3` i have JVM platform, and no matter how I declare dependencies, `module3` does not  see classes from  `module1` or they do not compile, are there any guide how to implement this particular use case?

Answer (score 0):

For this it's needed to have more than one `expectedBy` declaration, which for now is forbidden. But, as say in kotlin slack, it will be possible soon.

So, for now, it's needed to switch to version `1.2.40-dev-754` of kotlin, and then it will be possible to add second `expectedBy` to dependencies in build.gradle in `module3`: 
`expectedBy project(':module1')` 
`expectedBy project(':module2')`